# How to reloop program back to beginning

Tags: python, loops

How would I reloop this program back to ask the user for more input again? I am confused because if I use the `while True:` loop, it just prints out a whole bunch of the user's inputs.

```
userinput = str(input("enter a sentence: \n"))

def reverseinputs(x):

        string = []
        result = x.split(' ')
        string += reversed(result)
        print (' '.join(string))

reverseinputs(userinput)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def reverseinputs(x):
  ...
```

is a definition, and as such, doesn't execute anything (well, usually) and can safely be left out of the loop.

You seem to want to repeatedly ask the user for input and then process it with `reverseinputs()`. That task is achieved by the first line:

```
userinput = str(input("enter a sentence: \n"))
```

and the last line:

```
reverseinputs(userinput)
```

Placing those in a `while(True)` loop should yield the desired result:

```
def reverseinputs(x):
        string = []
        result = x.split(' ')
        string += reversed(result)
        print (' '.join(string))

while(True):
        userinput = str(input("enter a sentence: \n"))
        reverseinputs(userinput)
```

Your issue seems to come from misunderstanding `userinput` as a function, which would (with the right syntax) be executed each time it is referred to, giving a new input each time, rather than as a variable, which simply gives whatever value it was last assigned (in this case, the first user input).

**Sidenote**: As @diligar pointed out in the comments, it's always a good idea to give some way for the user to get out of an infinite loop. Something like this should work:

```
while(True):
    userinput = str(input("enter a sentence: \n"))
    if userinput == "": break
    ...
```

Comment: And then I usually include a failsafe in my `while True` loops, like `if userinput == "": break`

Comment: Some little flaws: you don't need parenthesis around `True`. Calling `str()` function is useless since `input()` already returns a `str`. The `if` condition can be written `if not userinput`.

Comment: You can use underscore in identifiers to have more readable names: `user_input`. Nowadays, IDEs have integrated smart spellcheckers which can help you to find misspelled variables in your code.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE: I was just taking the OPs code as is -- maybe these comments would be more helpful to them if made on the question itself?

Answer (score 2):

How about simply:

```
while True:
    userinput = input("enter a sentence: \n")
    if not userinput:
        break
    print(' '.join(reversed(userinput.split())))
```

Comment: This is the more Pythonic answer even if the Linuxios' answer is more detailed for newbies.

Answer (score 2):

Though more elegant ways exist, a quick and simple solution is to add this at the end of the function:

```
x = str(input("enter a sentence: \n"))
reverseinputs(x)
```

Essentially, you're creating a recursive function here. I think a more elegant solution is using the while loop like you mentioned like this:

```
def reverseinputs(x):
    string = []
    result = x.split(' ')
    string += reversed(result)
    print (' '.join(string))

while True:
    userinput = str(input("enter a sentence: \n"))
    reverseinputs(userinput)
```